# Can you mount a VeraCrypt partition to a folder?

Tags: encryption

I have recently encrypted a drive with multiple partitions using VeraCrypt. This is not the main drive with Windows installed on it, but a drive used to store data. Windows allows me to mount the partitions to a folder for seamless integration. I was hoping VeraCrypt would allow me to do this, also, but so far I have only been able to mount the encrypted partitions to a letter. Is there a way to mount it directly to a folder? I'm okay with a workaround, or indirect fix, if it can be automated.

For reference I'm running Windows 7 x64, but I'm also interested in knowing how to do this in Linux. I usually use Ubuntu variations, like Mint.

Answer (score 0):

Veracrypt on windows can only mount to a drive letter. But you can use symbolic links to link that drive to an arbitrary directory (a drive letter is needed anyway). In windows 10 use the command line tool mklink. After mounting your drive you can enter:

```
mklink /d /j c:\anydir t:
```

c:\anydir is the symbolic link that behaves like a regular folder, and t: is the truecrypt drive. For further information look for the help text:

```
mklink /?
```

If you don't have mklink on your system, try to google for it (there has been something like windows resource kit).